# How to use service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http())) instead of service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds) in python

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to build a gmail api service with the code. I already loaded my credentials as creds derived from https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python.

```py
from apiclient.discovery import build
service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
```

After running the code, I keep getting the error:

```
Credentials' object has no attribute 'http'
```

I do not want to use the google own which is

```
service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try:  http = httplib2.Http()  http = credentials.authorize(http)  build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)

Comment: When using a library you need to use it as it was designed.  The method does support what you are trying to do.   You need to pass build the proper credentials object

Comment: I have tried that @Dori. But I still have the same error message: 'Credentials' object has no attribute 'authorize'

Comment: How do I do that? @DalmTo.